# Java permutations of char array with repetition

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, char, permutation

I aim to make a function that generates all possible permutations with repetitions of char array -> for ex. ('a', 'b', 'c' ). After checking if everything is in arraylist allPerms, I found out that for ex. ('b', 'c', 'd') is not there. Any suggestions what am I missing?

```
public void permutations(char [] array, int length) {
    if (array[length-1] != '\0') {
        allPerms.add(array);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if(array[j] == '\0') {
                    array[j] = characters[i];
                    char[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(array, length);
                    permutations(copy, length);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `characters` is undefined, it will throw compile time exception. Need to fix it and put you query along with what you had tried.

Comment: nono, I just cut the part of the code that is doing trouble, everything else works well, characters is defined